# Passing multiple values from a PHP URL to a single row in a SQL table

Tags: php, sql, get

I'm trying to pass multiple values from a PHP URL using a Get statement. I feel like it should be pretty simple. I've managed to pass one variable fine but the second variable always ends up being NULL for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "prototype3DB";
$DB_User = "root";
$DB_Pass = "root";
$DB_Table = "sqlTable";


if (isset ($_GET["date"]))
$date = $_GET["date"];
else
$date = "null";

    if (isset ($_GET["fname"]))
    $fname = $_GET["fname"];
    else
    $fname = "null";


    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 


    $sql = "insert into $DB_Table (date, fname) values ('$date','$fname')";

    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($con);
    if ($res) {
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }// end else
?>
```

The date variable always gets passed to the database but fname is the one that ends up NULL.
I kind of have the feeling it's a problem with syntax but then again I'm pretty new to PHP.

Basically, I think this line is the problem:

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (date, fname) values ('$date','$fname')";
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: I _really_ hope you don't use the root user in your application. Combine that with your SQL injection vulnerabilities and you're screwed.

Comment: Run a `print_r($_GET)` to make sure you're passing it correctly... It should give you an array of `$_GET` values.

Comment: Show us the connection string you're trying to pass into it?  Minus domain name, of course.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. Use either PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (date, fname) values ('$date','".$fname."')";
```

Sometimes those extra quotes solve problems...lol

But Colin is right too....the vulnerability here is quite apparent.  Hopefully you're just testing things.. :)

Comment: Thanks this worked, and yeah, this is just going to run through a local host to a local database for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Please use PDO or MySQLi instead of the `mysql_*` functions. I like PDO and useful information can be found here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers  and http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

For a quick primer examine this code:

```
<?php

// Credentials. DSN is a string defining how to connect to the DB
$DB_DSN    = "mysql:dbname=myDatabase;host=127.0.0.1";
$DB_USER   = "myUser";
$DB_PASSWD = "myPassword";

// Make the connection and get a handle for talking to the db
$db = new PDO($DB_DSN, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWD);

// Make query into a prepared statement. Protects us from SQL injection.
// Use placeholders like :status and :id where we will be inserting variables
$statement = $db->prepare('
    UPDATE users
    SET status = :status
    WHERE id = :id ');

// Associate vars with the placeholders in our query
// Define the type of valus such as string or int with the third param
$statement->bindValue(':id',     $_GET['id'],     PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':status', $_GET['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Actually run the query
$statement->execute();
```